# Percentage change in grouped data: calculate against first value of group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to get the percentage change between the first value (of one variable) in a group and every other value (of the same variable) in the same group.

Example data:

```
df = data.frame(group = c(rep('A',4), rep('B',3)),
            response = c(1,4,2,1,1,2,3),
            treatment = c("control","100mg","200mg","50mg","control","100mg","200mg"))

> df
    group response treatment
       A     1   control
       A     4     100mg
       A     2     200mg
       A     1      50mg
       B     1   control
       B     2     100mg
       B     3     200mg
```

In other words, I'd like to get the percentage change in 
*response* relative to the *treatment* 'control' for all other levels of *treatment* in the same group. The number of levels of *treatment* can vary group by group.

What I have so far:

```
# function for % change
pct <- function(x) {(x/lag(x)-1)*100}

library(dplyr)
# group data and apply function
percChange <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(response), funs(pct))

# the output (perChange) is:

#   group response treatment
# 1 A        NA   control  
# 2 A       300   100mg    
# 3 A       -50   200mg    
# 4 A       -50   50mg     
# 5 B        NA   control  
# 6 B       100   100mg    
# 7 B        50   200mg
```

But the output I would like is:

```
# group  response  treatment
# 1 A        NA   control  
# 2 A       300   100mg    
# 3 A       100   200mg    
# 4 A       0     50mg     
# 5 B       NA    control  
# 6 B       100   100mg    
# 7 B       200   200mg
```

I have looked everywhere and found similar things but none are quite what I'm after. Thanks.

Comment: Is it important that control treatments have `NA`? Or is `0` (which is technically accurate) alright? Also, is the data ordered? That is, will `control` always be first, or is it important to match on the `treatment` value to find the first value?

Comment: @divibisan yup you're right - ideally 0 would be best! and I normally order the data so control would be first in the group. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `first()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(
  group = c(rep('A',4), rep('B',3)),
  response = c(1,4,2,1,1,2,3),
  treatment = c("control","100mg","200mg","50mg","control","100mg","200mg")
)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    resp_pct_chg_from_first = (response / first(response) - 1) * 100
  )
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>   group response treatment resp_pct_chg_from_first
#>   <fct>    <dbl> <fct>                       <dbl>
#> 1 A            1 control                         0
#> 2 A            4 100mg                         300
#> 3 A            2 200mg                         100
#> 4 A            1 50mg                            0
#> 5 B            1 control                         0
#> 6 B            2 100mg                         100
#> 7 B            3 200mg                         200
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

JasonAizkalns answered it well, but just in case you want to keep your `pct` function. Just fixing a small error in your `pct` function make it work.

```
pct <- function(x) {
  ((x-x[1])/x[1]) * 100
}

> percChange
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
  group response treatment
  <fct>    <dbl> <fct>    
1 A            0 control  
2 A          300 100mg    
3 A          100 200mg    
4 A            0 50mg     
5 B            0 control  
6 B          100 100mg    
7 B          200 200mg
```

Comment: Thanks @nsinghs! accepted the other one as it seems a more elegant way than what I had tried but I appreciate knowing where I was going wrong with function thank you.